# Convert an image in a PySpark dataframe to a Numpy array

Tags: numpy, pyspark, python-imaging-library

I have a DataFrame in PySpark (version 3.1.2) which contains images:

```
img_path = "s3://multimedia-commons/data/images/000/24a/00024a73d1a4c32fb29732d56a2.jpg"
df = spark.read.format("image").load(img_path)
df.printSchema()
df.select("image.height", "image.width"
         ,"image.nChannels", "image.mode"
         ,"image.data").show()
```

```
root
 |-- image: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- origin: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- height: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- width: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- nChannels: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mode: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- data: binary (nullable = true)

+------+-----+---------+----+--------------------+
|height|width|nChannels|mode|                data|
+------+-----+---------+----+--------------------+
|   260|  500|        3|  16|[00 00 00 00 00 0...|
+------+-----+---------+----+--------------------+
```

I need to convert the image into a Numpy array to pass to a machine learning model.

The approach in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69215982/11262633 seems reasonable, but is giving me incorrect image values.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml.image import ImageSchema
from pyspark.ml.linalg import DenseVector, VectorUDT
import numpy as np

img2vec = F.udf(lambda x: DenseVector(ImageSchema.toNDArray(x).flatten()), VectorUDT())

print(f'Image fields = {ImageSchema.imageFields}')
df_new = df.withColumn('vecs',img2vec('image'))

row_dict = df_new.first().asDict()
img_vec = row_dict['vecs']

img_dict = row_dict['image']
width = img_dict['width']
height = img_dict['height']
nChannels = img_dict['nChannels']
img_np = img_vec.reshape(height, width, nChannels)

m = np.ma.masked_greater(img_np, 100)
m_mask = m.mask
args = np.argwhere(m_mask)
for idx, (r, c, _) in enumerate(args):
    print(r, c, img_np[r,c])
    if idx > 5:
        break
```

Output:

```
46 136 [  0.  13. 101.]
47 104 [  1.  15. 102.]
47 105 [  1.  16. 104.]
47 106 [  1.  16. 104.]
47 107 [  1.  16. 104.]
47 108 [  1.  16. 104.]
47 109 [  1.  15. 105.]
```

Here's a visualization of the image:

[image]

**Desired Results**

Reading the image using Pillow gives a different result:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('/home/hadoop/00024a73d1a4c32fb29732d56a2.jpg')
img_np = np.asarray(img)
m = np.ma.masked_greater(img_np, 100)
m_mask = m.mask
args = np.argwhere(m_mask)
for idx, (r, c, _) in enumerate(args):
    print(r, c, img_np[r,c])
    if idx > 5:
        break
```

Output:

```
47 104 [101  16   9]
47 105 [103  16   9]
47 106 [103  16   9]
47 107 [103  16   9]
47 108 [103  16   9]
47 109 [104  15   9]
47 110 [105  16  10]
```

[image]

**My question**

***Why are the images different, both in appearance, and when I read individual pixels?***

Using `np.asarray` on the bytes data returned by PySpark gave the same issue.  Maybe PySpark is fine and there's just some error in my manipulations of the returned data.  I've spent about 8 hours working on this.  Thanks in advance for any insights you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because [spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-datasource.html#image-data-source) uses

> data: BinaryType (Image bytes in OpenCV-compatible order: row-wise BGR
> in most cases)

And Pillow is rendering it RGB.